# pcap_dispatch hangs on

Tags: pcap, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, winpcap

Hi I have a program in which i capture the packets with pcap in python.

```
filter=some_filter 
promiscuous= True
read_timeout= 50 # msec
self.pcap= pcapy.open_live(self.ifname, self.conf.capture_snaplen, promiscuous, read_timeout)
self.pcap.setfilter(filter)
```

This is the configuration and i call the dispatch function with my callback.The print statements are for debug

```
while True:
            print "dispatch is called"
            return_value=self.pcap.dispatch(packet_limit, self.distribute_packet)
            print "return value"
            print return_value
```

So I run this system on 2 hosts with different networks.The Oses are freebsd 9.0 release

One of the system is working fine and it writes my debug truely;

```
dispatch is called
return vaue
34,45,55 whatever it is
```

But the other system is;

```
dispatch is called
```

and nothing. So it hangs up at the dispatch function. It does not return anything and hang up.The two systems are identical but they are on different networks.I tried to change the timeout of pcap.openlive. But it does not matter.
Why does it hang up?

Comment: Does `tcpdump` work on this other system?

Comment: Perhaps you can see in what system call the program hangs by using a trace tool (truss, ktrace, dtrace, strace, ...).